# Crear Trigger en Sql Server el cual me insert un dato generado despues de una insert

Tags: sql-server, trigger

Mi consulta es como crear un trigger en Sql Server, el cual realice una inserción con el id generado a otra tabla. Todo surge con la necesidad la cual radica al momento de yo realizar una inserción a una tabla, necesito el id que se genero en esa tabla para insertarlo en otra tabla.

Comment: Podrias mostrar que es lo que requieres y la tabla que se afecta, y a cual afectarias posteriormente?

Comment: Para darte un ejemplo: la tabla 1 posee( Id autonómico y un varchar ),la tabla 2 posee(un Id autonumerico, un integer id_tabla1, y un varchar). La idea consiste, a la hora de yo insertar un dato en la tabla 1. Inmediatamente luego se la inserción un trigger se debe de ejecutar obtener el Id que se generó en la tabla 1 y luego agarre ese Id y lo inserte en la tabla 2 con unos datos por defecto

Comment: te anexe el ejemplo saludos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Con base a tu comentario te anexo el ejemplo saludos

```
--CREAMOS LA TABLA 1
CREATE TABLE Table1(
ID INT IDENTITY(1,1),
Nombre NVARCHAR(50)
);
--CREAMOS LA TABLA 2
CREATE TABLE TABLE2(
ID INT IDENTITY(1,1),
IDTabla1 INT,
Nombre NVARCHAR(50)
);
GO
--CREAMOS EL TRIGGER QUE CUANDO SE INSERTE UN REGISTRO EN LA TABLA UNO SE INSERTE EN LA TABLA 2
CREATE TRIGGER InsertTable2  
ON Table1 
AFTER INSERT
AS  
DECLARE @IDTable2 INT =(SELECT ID FROM inserted )
   INSERT INTO TABLE2 VALUES(@IDTable2,'Test insert from table 1 con ID ' + CAST(@IDTable2 AS nvarchar(50)))
GO  

--INSERTAMOS REGISTROS EN LA TABLA 1 PARA QUE SE INSERTEN EN LA TABLA 2

INSERT INTO Table1 VALUES ('Edgar Vazquez')--ID 1
INSERT INTO Table1 VALUES ('Edgar Vazquez 2')--ID 2


SELECT * FROM TABLE2
```

Aqui puedes ver el funcionamiento

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/380ee4/3

Comment: Muchas gracias Edgar Vazquez. Este código es precisamente lo que necesitaba.

Comment: De nada. Saludos

Answer (score 0):

Crea un trigger con AFTER. En la tabla **inserted** tienes acceso a todos los datos insertados

[CREATE TRIGGER (Transact-SQL)](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/t-sql/statements/create-trigger-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

Comment: Será que pueda darme un ejemplo de ello?